# How to recursively reduce denormalized table into a nested json string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a tree that is stored in tabular format, like this:

| name | id | isRoot | childId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36664 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36665 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36666 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36667 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36668 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36669 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36670 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36671 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36672 |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | 36673 |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | 36680 |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | 36681 |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | 36682 |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | 36683 |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | 36684 |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | 36685 |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | 36686 |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | 36687 |
| regions | 36666 | 0 | 36693 |
| regions | 36666 | 0 | 36694 |
| regions | 36666 | 0 | 36695 |
| regions | 36666 | 0 | 36696 |
| regions | 36666 | 0 | 36697 |
| regions | 36667 | 0 | 36713 |
| regions | 36667 | 0 | 36714 |
| regions | 36667 | 0 | 36715 |
| regions | 36667 | 0 | 36716 |
| regions | 36667 | 0 | 36717 |
| regions | 36668 | 0 | 36698 |
| regions | 36668 | 0 | 36699 |
| regions | 36668 | 0 | 36700 |
| regions | 36668 | 0 | 36701 |
| regions | 36668 | 0 | 36702 |
| regions | 36668 | 0 | 36703 |
| regions | 36668 | 0 | 36704 |
| ... etc |  |  |  |

That I am trying to convert into a single row:

| name | termId | tree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| regions | 36663 | {"children":[{"id":36664, "children": [{"id": , "children": [...etc]}, ...etc]}]} |

I've got as far as producing a table that contains fragments of a single tree from the perspective of each node:

| tree | id | isRoot | fragment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| regions | 36663 | 1 | {"children":[{"id":36664},{"id":36665},{"id":36666},{"id":36667},{"id":36668},{"id":36669},{"id":36670},{"id":36671},{"id":36672},{"id":36673}]} |
| regions | 36664 | 0 | {} |
| regions | 36665 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36680},{"id":36681},{"id":36682},{"id":36683},{"id":36684},{"id":36685},{"id":36686},{"id":36687}]} |
| regions | 36666 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36693},{"id":36694},{"id":36695},{"id":36696},{"id":36697}]} |
| regions | 36667 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36713},{"id":36714},{"id":36715},{"id":36716},{"id":36717}]} |
| regions | 36668 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36698},{"id":36699},{"id":36700},{"id":36701},{"id":36702},{"id":36703},{"id":36704},{"id":36705},{"id":36706},{"id":36707},{"id":36708}]} |
| regions | 36669 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36721},{"id":36722},{"id":36723},{"id":36724},{"id":36725}]} |
| regions | 36670 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36718},{"id":36719},{"id":36720}]} |
| regions | 36671 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36709},{"id":36710},{"id":36711},{"id":36712}]} |
| regions | 36672 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36688},{"id":36689},{"id":36690},{"id":36691},{"id":36692}]} |
| regions | 36673 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36674},{"id":36675},{"id":36676},{"id":36677},{"id":36678},{"id":36679}]} |
| regions | 36674 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36752},{"id":36753},{"id":36754},{"id":36755},{"id":36756}]} |
| regions | 36675 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36761},{"id":36762},{"id":36763}]} |
| regions | 36676 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36770}]} |
| regions | 36677 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36781},{"id":36782},{"id":36783},{"id":36784},{"id":36785},{"id":36786},{"id":36787}]} |
| regions | 36678 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36857},{"id":36858},{"id":36859},{"id":36860}]} |
| regions | 36679 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36918},{"id":36919},{"id":36920},{"id":36921},{"id":36922}]} |
| regions | 36680 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36726},{"id":36727},{"id":36728},{"id":36729}]} |
| regions | 36681 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36733},{"id":36734},{"id":36735},{"id":36736},{"id":36737},{"id":36738}]} |
| regions | 36682 | 0 | {"children":[{"id":36744}]} |

... there are 276 rows in total

And I'm unsure where to go from here. I'm aware of recursive CTEs, but not as a means for recursively building a JSON string. How can I do this?

The concepts I'm struggling with:

- If I recursively `UNION ALL` that results in additional rows, which I don't want
- If I `cross apply` the `openjson(children)` of the 'fragments' then I get the original table again... which I don't want

I see a similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41823306/3114742) that says it's not possible to use a recursive CTE to recursively build a JSON tree. I think it's worth re-asking this question since the answer is now 5 years old. I'm currently using SQL Server 2017, but can update to SQL Server 2019 if that would provide a solution to this.

Comment: Same here :)
I spent some time wrestling with uptake of the `FOR JSON PATH` as an easy output from normal query, but inevitably, I ended up with the same, denormalized (read: repetitive), well-structured json. To prepare the underlying, nested subquery `SELECT`s, I also spent a little bit of time working with https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-grouping-sets/ to no avail.
I only _90% think_ it's not possible in this manner, but I fell back to "let the application do the work" of iterating the denormalized resultset and building my pojo manually.